# How to SSL termination in docker traefik for using varnish

Tags: docker, varnish, traefik

I am using docker traefik and behind that varnish to cache and my website is behind of varnish.
This is  docker-compose for my website and varnish services:

```yaml
version: "3.7"


services:
  dev-ui-service:
    image: mywebsite.ui:latest
    networks:
      - localnetwork

  varnish:
    image: myvarnish:latest
    deploy:
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.ui.rule=Host(`mydomain.com`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.ui.entrypoints=web"
        - "traefik.http.services.ui.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
        - "traefik.http.routers.ui-secured.rule=Host(`mydomain.com`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.ui-secured.entrypoints=web-secured"
        - "traefik.http.routers.ui-secured.tls.certresolver=mytlschallenge"
        - "traefik.docker.network=traefik-proxy"
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.5'
          memory: 200M
        reservations:
          cpus: '0.2'
          memory: 20M
    networks:
      - localnetwork
      - traefik-proxy
    depends_on:
      - dev-ui-service

networks:
  localnetwork:
  traefik-proxy:
    external: true
```

and this is my default.vcl file:

```
vcl 4.0;
backend default {
  .host = "dev-ui-service";
  .port = "4200";
}

# If you don't include below, header Age in response to client always be 0

sub vcl_deliver {
  # Display hit/miss info
  if (obj.hits > 0) {
    set resp.http.V-Cache = "HIT";
  }
  else {
    set resp.http.V-Cache = "MISS";
  }
  set resp.http.Access-Control-Allow-Origin = "*";
  set resp.http.Access-Control-Allow-Headers = "Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Mx-ReqToken,X-Requested-With";
  set resp.http.Allow = "GET, POST";
  set resp.http.Access-Control-Allow-Credentials = "true";
  set resp.http.Access-Control-Allow-Methods = "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, PATCH";
  set resp.http.Access-Control-Expose-Headers = "X-Pagination-Total, X-Pagination-Page, X-Pagination-Limit";
}
sub vcl_backend_response {
  if (beresp.status == 200) {
    unset beresp.http.Cache-Control;
    set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "public; max-age=200";
    set beresp.ttl = 200s;
  }
  set beresp.http.Served-By = beresp.backend.name;
  set beresp.http.V-Cache-TTL = beresp.ttl;
  set beresp.http.V-Cache-Grace = beresp.grace;
}
```

Every things is ok but varnish not support https so all request from https MISS.
How do I SSL termination when request send from traefik to varnish?

Answer (score 1):

### Built-in VCL behavior

Your VCL extends the standard behavior of the `vcl_deliver` and `vcl_backend_response` subroutines. Because you didn't provide any logic for `vcl_recv`, Varnish's built-in VCL behavior will be used.

As a matter of fact, Varnish always uses the built-in VCL unless the subroutine in question is overridden.

See https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/blob/6.0/bin/varnishd/builtin.vcl

### Why the miss?

```
If we look at the built-in VCL for `vcl_recv`, you'll see that there are some caching rules in place:

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.method == "PRI") {
        /* This will never happen in properly formed traffic (see: RFC7540) */
        return (synth(405));
    }
    if (!req.http.host &&
      req.esi_level == 0 &&
      req.proto ~ "^(?i)HTTP/1.1") {
        /* In HTTP/1.1, Host is required. */
        return (synth(400));
    }
    if (req.method != "GET" &&
      req.method != "HEAD" &&
      req.method != "PUT" &&
      req.method != "POST" &&
      req.method != "TRACE" &&
      req.method != "OPTIONS" &&
      req.method != "DELETE" &&
      req.method != "PATCH") {
        /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
        return (pipe);
    }

    if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
        /* We only deal with GET and HEAD by default */
        return (pass);
    }
    if (req.http.Authorization || req.http.Cookie) {
        /* Not cacheable by default */
        return (pass);
    }
    return (hash);
}
```

A cache miss occurs when the following conditions are true:

- A request method other than `GET` or `HEAD`
- The request contains an `Authorization` header
- The request contains a `Cookie` header

> The most likely situation is that the requests that cause a *MISS* contain a cookie.

### How to turn the misses into hits

Assuming that cookies are the problem, you should write some VCL logic inside `vcl_recv` and determine which cookies are kept and which cookies should be deleted.

Most tracking cookies have no server-side impact and can be deleted.

Other cookies are used by the application and cannot be deleted.

If a specific URL resource requires a cookie value, you can use `return(pass)` to ensure that Varnish doesn't cache it.

Other pages that don't require the cookie value, can have these cookies stripped to ensure cache hits.

For pages that require cookies, but where the cookie value has a low and controllable variations, you can use cache variations and cache the cookie value inside `vcl_hash`.

> Again, I'm assuming that cookies are the reason why the cache miss occurs.

## How to optimize TLS termination

The open source version of Varnish doesn't support native TLS, so termination is required.

Varnish facilitates TLS termination by support the [PROXY protocol](https://www.haproxy.org/download/1.8/doc/proxy-protocol.txt). Apparently [Traefik supports it as well](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/services/#proxy-protocol).

You can enable PROXY protocol at the Varnish level by opening up an extra listening port.

Whereas a simplified HTTP-only `varnishd` command can look like this:

```
varnishd -a :80 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl
```

A PROXY-powered `varnishd` command could look like this:

```
varnishd -a :80 -a :8443,PROXY -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl
```

As you can see, I added an extra listening interface on port `8443` which only supports PROXY traffic. Port `80` is stil active for regular HTTP traffic.

You can then configure Traefik to terminate TLS and to route traffic to Varnish. If you enable PROXY protocol on Traefik, Varnish will be able to leverage the protocol.

In VCL, you could then detect HTTP/HTTPS requests, using the following VCL snippet:

```
vcl 4.1;

import proxy;

sub vcl_recv {
    if (proxy.is_ssl()) {
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto = "https";
    } else {
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto = "http";
    }
}
```

And then you could return a `Vary: X-Forwarded-Proto` response header in your application, to create a cache variation based on the protocol.

Another advantage of the PROXY protocol is that the `X-Forwarded-For` header always contains the client IP address of the original client, regardless of the number of hops.